# Do Docker images save the memory state?

Tags: docker

Very new to docker, apologies for the trivial question. I'm currently using a VM and creating live snapshots (which of course save the state of the memory, etc), such that when I revert its at that exact moment. Do Docker snapshots work in a similar way? If I snapshot it with a running application will it restore to that same state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  It saves "layers", which are essentially overlays on the file system, with some other magic for environment variables, ports, etc.  No memory state is saved whatever.

Answer (score 14):

The [CRIU project](http://criu.org/) is working on technology which will make it easy to  checkpoint and migrate containers, including RAM snapshots.

Comment: It's now an experimental feature in Docker https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md

Comment: @user276648 broken link :|

Comment: @AlonGouldman It was moved to the CLI: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md

Comment: And it moved again: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/checkpoint.md